# Parse error javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi all i am having an error below error cause by the last part , could anyone point out whats wrong

Error Prompt:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';`'

Error at this line:

```
 <a> onClick="editstatus('+obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave +')" </a>
```

Full Code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {'wid' : wid},
    success: function(data)
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        $("#WorkerName").text(name + " Leave Application");

        $.each (obj.leaveType, function (bb) {

            $( "#tbody-"+obj.leaveType[bb].idleavetype ).empty();

            $.each (obj.leaveRecords, function (aa) {

                if(obj.leaveType[bb].idleavetype == obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleavetype)
                {
                    var leaveid = obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave ;
                    console.log(leaveid);

                    $('#tbody-'+obj.leaveType[bb].idleavetype).append('<tr><td>'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].reason+'</td><td>'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].startleaveDate+'</td><td>'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].endleaveDate+'</td><td>'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].nameStatus+'</td><td>'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].name+'</td><td>'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].ApproveOn+'</td><?php if($groupid == 3){ echo '<td> <a> onClick="editstatus('+obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave +')" </a></td>';  }?></tr>');                                          
                }                                       
            });                                     
        });                                
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the nesting of `'` inside the PHP echo string.

Comment: its a javascript json

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into your question body: accept the answer that helped you the most, or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The echo in your PHP needs to escape the inner single quotes:

```
echo '<td><a class="btn btn-warning form-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#arform" onClick="editstatus(\' + obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave + \')" >Change Status</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

the onClick call `'+obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave +'`
contains the mistake. You don't need to wrap it with `+` and `'`

Try this instead:
`<a> onClick="editstatus(obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave)" </a>`

Comment: extracted from html inspect 

<a class="btn btn-warning form-group" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#arform" onclick="editstatus(obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave)">Change Status</a>

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably in this part of your code:

```
onClick="editstatus('+obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave +')"
```

Try replacing it with this one:

```
onClick="editstatus(obj.leaveRecords[aa].idleave)"
```

You don't need to use `'+` inside the parameters of the function.